$\mathbb Z$-modules
We know that all abelian groups are $\mathbb Z$-modules via the 'natural' definition $n.g= g+g+\dots+g,\ $  (n times).
Are they other $\mathbb Z$-modules? I mean other abelian groups that are $\mathbb Z$-modules but with another action $m.g= \sigma_m(g)$ for $m\in \mathbb Z$ .

You can define $n.g=g+g+\cdots+g$ $2n$ times (or $3n$ times or …).

No, recall that modules need to satisfy $1x=x$. Apart from that, as a highly active member, you probably know that comments should not be used for posting answers. See How do comments work for more information.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you. So every $R$-module (for any ring $R$) is a $\mathbb Z$-module. This makes me think that $\mathbb Z$-modules are not interesting, and the name is redundant with abelian groups. Unless there is something that I am missing?

No. Module-theoretic concepts apply in particular to $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and hence to abelian groups. Even though you can, of course, describe them directly for abelian groups, the extra structure is useful. You will learn this once you dig a bit deeper into algebra. A similar example: elementary abelian $p$-groups are the same as $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces. This does not make $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces less interesting. Quite the opposite.
